# How does the "link-only answer" comment get generated?

Tags: support, review, flags

Here is an example:

[Add indication that canned comments are from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271829/6754053)
[image]

This never shows up for me in the First Posts review queue.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek updated link.

Comment: It’s from the VLQ review queue.